# Changing "Use Flat Catalog Category/Product" To Yes Changes The Head Of My Website

Tags: magento-1.9, flat-catalog, magento-1.9.2.1

Recently we have decided to change the option of our website to use the flat catalogue category/product to speed up our website, which works!
But we have now come across a problem where when doing this it changes the header of the website back some part of the original theme which is strange:

[image: The header here seems to be the original header but showing some of the original theme at top and changing the layout of components in our theme]

We are running on magento version: 1.9.2.1

Comment: any custom modules that affect the menu or top cart area? could be cause. Disable modules you suspect then refresh